# Node.js: HTTP get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am trying  to write a node.js script as follows

```
var https = require('https');
var options = {
  hostname: 'https://172.16.2.51',
  port: 9090,
  path: '/vm/list',
  method: 'GET',                
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.end();
req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

When I run the script, I get this error:

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }
```

Answer (score 3):

The `hostname` property of `options` should be an IP address or a domain name. In your example, get rid of the protocol. So change this:

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'https://172.16.2.51',
  port: 9090,
  path: '/vm/list',
  method: 'GET'
};
```

To this:

```
var options = {
  hostname: '172.16.2.51',
  port: 9090,
  path: '/vm/list',
  method: 'GET'
};
```